# Using Ansible become password in a task

Tags: macos, ansible, ansible-vault

My playbook is invoked with `--ask-become-pass`. The become password is supplied via an environmental variable on the Control machine.

Everything is working just fine for the *many* tasks I have which require privilege escalation. However, there's one or two tasks that require the password directly as part of the command. E.g. I was hoping I could use something like:
`command: /foo/bar autoLoginUser {{ ansible_become_pass }}`

...but I get the following: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_become_pass' is undefined."

I'd rather not duplicate this password in the Vault if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to supply the become password. As per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html):

> - providing the --ask-become-pass command line option
> - setting the ansible_become_password connection variable

This variable can be set in the inventory, like so:

```
webserver01 ansible_user=ansible ansible_become_password=secret
```

Or supplied from the command line instead of `--ask-become-pass`. Like so:

```
export MY_PASSWORD=secret
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -e "ansible_become_password=$MY_PASSWORD"
```

Since this variable is now set, you can then have tasks like:

```yaml
command: "/foo/bar autoLoginUser {{ ansible_become_password }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an environmental variable you could use `lookup` as below

```yaml
- name: Execute command
  command: /foo/bar autoLoginUser {{ lookup('env', 'YOUR_VAR') }}
```

Comment: Thanks @gary-lopez I had considered that - it's probably my Plan B - the only problem is it's a little incovenient for devs (who know the the password) to use directly.